# Centering left floated content twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to the twitter bootstrap world and % based widths and am confusing myself greatly with what should be an easy thing to accomplish.

I'm trying to center each of the left floated `.subimg` on my page. Obviously `margin:0 auto` won't work because it's not a static grid. I've used text-align centers on parent divs to no avail. My markup is below:

```
<style>
.subimg{float:left;}
.row-fluid{text-align:center;}
</style>

<div class="row-fluid"><!-- begin row -->
    <div class="span12 subimgstrip">
            <div class="subimg">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/img/products/infection/1.jpg"/>
                    <h6>Customize Settings</h6>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subimg">
                <a href="#">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/img/products/infection/2.jpg"/>
                        <h6>Set Specific Criteria</h6>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subimg">
                <a href="#">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/img/products/infection/3.jpg"/>
                        <h6>Customize Alerts</h6>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subimg">
                <a href="#">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/img/products/infection/4.jpg"/>
                        <h6>Create Antibiograms</h6>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subimg">
                <a href="#">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/img/products/infection/5.jpg"/>
                        <h6>Isolate Information</h6>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end row -->
```

Comment: you can't center something that is floated unless you know the width or the parent then you can apply the correct margin to make your floated div appear centered

Comment: right, just realized that i'm taking the content out of its set area with the float (duhh moment) `display:inline-block` seems to fix it for me. Any reason why I shouldn't use that?

Comment: no reason I can think of

Answer (score 0):

Best way to center floated content with twitter bootstrap is to give the floated items a style of `display:inline-block;` and give the parent div a style of `text-align:center`